# MYSQL multiple INT's in one row

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to figure out the best way to store some data in my database. I plan on joining 3 different tables.

```
users table
fighters table
moveset table
```

In the fighters table I have a row for 'moveset' in which I am trying to figure out a way that move_id's from the moveset table can then be associated within the fighters table under the moveset row so each fighter can list a bunch of moves that belongs to them.

Ex.

*fighters table has*

```
fighter_id,
fighter_name,
moveset
```

*moveset table has*

```
move_id,
move_name,
move_damage
```

Multiple move_id's need to get put in the moveset row in the fighters table.

Any help on how to set this up properly in mysql?

Comment: Do you have the concept if a "set of moves" that have reasonable reuse? Like a "move profile" that could be used to assign to one or more flights as a single thing?

Answer (score 2):

You need a "many-to-many" relationship.

To store this, the best way is by creating an *association* table, which has the key if both tables being related:

```
fighter_moves
-------------
id
fighter_id
move_id
```

You can even add other non-key columns, called *assoiation data*, that describe the relationship. For example, `speed` to define *how fast* the fighter does the move.

Comment: So basically create 4 tables. The 3 I have a above for details and 1 to tie them all together by id?

Comment: Yes. It's the only (sane) way to represent a many to many, which is what you have. Your design fine.

Comment: But if I have over 500 moves and over 1000 fighters, and each fighter has 50-100 moves, that could get problematic, no?

Comment: No, it will be ok. Another option, if you don't need to have a  fighter_moves `id` column, is to make `fighter_id` and `move_id` a compound primary key of the fighter_moves table (this will act as a unique constraint + index for free).

Comment: So then no matter what I would have to associate each move to each fighter over and over rather than have an "array-like" or something similar in MYSQL to link multiple moves to one fighter in a database?

Comment: that's a lot of queries just for two fighters to fight each other and use a ton of moves each.